# How Deficient a Number is? (Finding numbers having a certain deficiency)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

This question was edited, in particular equations were corrected:

A number N is said to be deficient by an integer $d$ if:

$\sigma(N)=2N-d$

Note that powers of 2 are deficient by 1.

While a prime $p$ is deficient by $p-1$

My question will be this:

Is there an integer $N$ that is deficient by an integer $d$ that lies between $(2/3)N$ and $N-\sqrt{N}$, that is

$(2/3)N<d<N-\sqrt{N}$ and can we characterize them?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What sigma is? It must be given a special function already known because if not d could be arbitrary,

Comment: I got in Google what sigma means.

Comment: The sum of divisor function Sir @LuisGomezSanchez.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\sigma(n)>0$ we have $d<2N$, together with $(2/3)N^2<d$ we get $(2/3)N^2<2N$ which is verified only for $0< N< 3$, which leaves only 2 cases to be checked, namely $1$ and $2$.

edit:After the question being asked has been changed the first part of my answer is irrelevant. I can't completely answer the new question, but I can show some solutions.

Consider a pair of twin primes $p$ and $p+2$ and their product $N=p^2+2p$.
$\sigma(N)$ is clearly given by $1+p+p+2+p^2+2p$, that is $\sigma(N)=p^2+4p+2$. 
 From $\sigma(N)=2N-d$ we get $d=2(p^2+2p)-(p^2+4p+2)=p^2-3$

Substituting into the inequality $(2/3)N<d<N-\sqrt{N}$ we get
$$\frac{2}{3}(p^2+2p)<p^2-3<p^2+2p-\sqrt{p^2+2p}$$
The left inequality is satisfied for $p>2+\sqrt{13}$ while the right one is satisfied for $p\ge0$.

So as long as $p$ and $p+2$ are both prime and $p\ge11$ their product is a number with the required deficiency (whether there are infinite pairs of twin primes is an exercise left to the reader :P).

For example consider $p=29$, that gives $N=899$, $\sigma(N)=960$,  $(2/3)N=599.33...$, $d=838$ and $N-\sqrt{N}=869.01...$

An analogous reasoning shows that if $p$ and $p+4$ are both primes and $p\ge7$ then their product is another solution, for example $77=7\times11$ and $221=13\times 17$. I suspect this can be generalized to more semiprimes, maybe all of them bigger than a certain number?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alessandro, my question will be are you saying that 1 and 2 are the only solution?

Comment: @JrAntalan You need to verify for yourself that neither $1$ nor $2$ satisfy this.

Comment: Verified that already @JeppeStigNielsen. Prior to this question I verified that the Right member of inequality is greater than the left member for $(3,\infty)$ but I want to find particular $N$ satisfying the above inequality and if possible, characterize them.

Comment: One can use the inequality $\frac23 N^2 < N^2-N$ from the question, directly to eliminate those two cases, so again we do not need to actually calculate any $\sigma$ value.

Comment: Thanks again @JeppeStigNielsen, does it mean that we do not have a solution?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, an edit has been made.

Comment: @JrAntalan Arter you made the edit, it is a new problem. This time it is not hard to find an `N` that works, like $N=11\cdot 13$.

Comment: @JrAntalan I edited my answer showing some $N$, basically generalizing the comment from Jeppe

Comment: Thanks Jeppe and Alessandro, an upvote for that :-).

Comment: @Alessandro , Nice answer and observation. I have another question, Is it possible that $N$ is a perfect square? That is, is does the inequality holds if $N$ is a perfect square? Thanks

Comment: @JrAntalan It holds if $N$ is the square of a prime $p$, with $p>\frac{1}{2}(3+\sqrt{21})$ (you can show it like I did in my answer, just pick $p$ and $p$ instead of $p$ and $p+2$), for example consider $N=25$, then we have $\sigma(N)=31$, $d=19$, $(2/3)N=16.66...$ and $N-\sqrt{N}=20$. I can't think of a simple way to deal with the case where $N$ is the square of a composite number

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro, will try the last case.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try using the following [criterion](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6767):

Let $1 < d = 2N - \sigma(N)$.  Then
$$\frac{2N}{N + d} < I(N) < \frac{2N + d}{N + d}$$
where $I(N)=\sigma(N)/N$ is the abundancy index of $N$.

Since you require
$$\frac{2}{3}N < d < N - \sqrt{N},$$
then we have
$$\frac{2}{3} < \frac{d}{N} = 2 - I(N) < 1 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}$$
so that we obtain
$$\frac{2}{2 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}}< \frac{2}{1 + \frac{d}{N}} = \frac{2N}{N+d} < I(N) < \frac{2N+d}{N+d} = \frac{2+\frac{d}{N}}{1+\frac{d}{N}} < \frac{3 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}}{\frac{5}{3}} = \frac{3}{5}\left(3 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}\right).$$

However, from
$$\frac{2}{3} < \frac{d}{N} = 2 - I(N) < 1 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}$$
you have the bounds
$$1 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}} < I(N) < \frac{4}{3},$$
so that
$$\frac{2}{2 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}}<I(N)<\frac{4}{3}$$
and
$$1 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}<I(N)<\frac{3}{5}\left(3 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}\right).$$

The first inequality yields:
$$6 < 8 - 4\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}} \implies 4\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}} < 2 \implies 2 < \sqrt{N} \implies 4 < N.$$
The second inequality yields:
$$5\sqrt{N} + 5 < 9\sqrt{N} - 3 \implies 8 < 4\sqrt{N} \implies 2 < \sqrt{N} \implies 4 < N.$$